# How to add a LINQ TO SQL Class in my ASP.NET-5 Project?

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-core

In my previous visual studio project I can just add new item "Linq to SQL class"  now in visual studio 2015 vnext project I dont have that option.

Answer (score 0):

It's no supported for now, but you  can use entity framework 7